# Insert data from another table and also from form in MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert, form-submit

i have a form where i post the data to mysql. the query should insert the data from the form into table1, but also include data from another table2 where the ID that is send from the form is equal to the ID in table2?

i use the old mysql connection, i know, not the best :-) and php!

hope someone can help, thanks :-)
Martin

think maybe I should give some more info :-)

table1 is called: books

from the form, i have the following value: itemCode, itemQty, ownerID
i have 2 static value: status, type

the values from table2 that must be inserted into table1 is: 
title, description, price, frontcover

from table2 the field isbn should be equal to itemCode from form.

here is what i have tried so far:

```
    $bookid=$_POST['itemCode'];
$itemQty=$_POST['itemQty'];
$status='2';
$ownerID = $user->id;

$query="INSERT INTO books (name, description, price, picture, status, ownerID, itemqty, type, studie, isbn) SELECT (title, description, price, frontcover FROM isbnbooks WHERE isbn=$itemCode), $status, $ownerID, $itemQty, '1', '1', $bookid)";
```

UPDATE:
I have also tried this one here:

```
$bookid=$_POST['itemCode'];
        $itemQty=$_POST['itemQty'];
        $status='2';
        $ownerID = $user->id;

        $data2 = mysql_fetch_array (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM isbnbooks WHERE isbn = $bookid"));
        $title = $data2[title];
        $description = $data2[description];
        $price = $data2[price];
        $picture = $data2[frontcover];

        $query="INSERT INTO books (name, description, price, picture, status, ownerID, itemqty, type, studie, isbn) 
        VALUES ($title, $description, $price, $picture, $status, $ownerID, $itemQty, '1', '1', $bookid)";
        mysql_query($query) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
```

Comment: think maybe I should give some more info :-)

Comment: My revised answer takes account of the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have values `'a'` and `'b'` to go into columns `f1` and `f2` of `table1`; and in `f3` you want the value of `table2.field` where `table2.id` is 123, you can prepare and execute a SQL statement along these lines:

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 (f1, f2, f3)
  SELECT 'a', 'b', field FROM table2 WHERE id = 123;
```

---

Further to seeing the code in your updated question, the problem with your first attempt is that you're trying to mix `INSERT ... SELECT` with `INSERT ... VALUES`; sadly they are mutually exclusive.  However, you could write instead:

```sql
INSERT INTO books (
  name,
  description,
  price,
  picture,
  status,
  ownerID,
  itemqty,
  type,
  studie,
  isbn
)
  SELECT
    title,
    description,
    price,
    frontcover,
    :status,  -- use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection
    :ownerID, -- see http://bobby-tables.com/ for more info
    :itemQty,
    '1',      -- do you really want a string containing a number?
    '1',
    :bookid
  FROM isbnbooks
  WHERE isbn=:itemCode;
```

Your second attempt looks as though it ought to work (although you really should use prepared statements, see above!); what problems are you having with it?

Answer (score 0):

in the absence of code, here's the workflow id recommend:

Form is submitted -> check and sanitize values - > execute lookup query against "table 2" and get your related values -> commit the update query with both form and "table2" data -> on successful update, notify user that their information was processed -> thank them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? :

```
$data2 = mysql_fetch_array (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id2 = '1'"));

$data1 = data2['column2'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('value1','$data2') WHERE id1 = id2);
```